# Rails - Simple search function

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm fairly new to rails and am building an online shop just to write some rails. I'm in the process of implementing a simple search function at the moment and get some strange behaviour I can't explain.

Model method:

```
def self.search(query)
  where("title like ?", "%#{query}%")
end
```

Controller methode:

```
def index
  if params[:search]
    @products = Product.search(params[:search])
  else
    @products = []
    #Only lists available products (in cart counts as available)
    @available_items = Item.where(user_id: nil).select(:product_id).uniq
    @available_items.each do |item|
      @products << item.product
    end
  end
end
```

Search form:

```
<%= form_tag(products_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form", enforce_utf8: false) do %>
  <%= text_field :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search..." %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

When I trigger a search I get no results and the url looks like this:

> http://localhost:3000/products?search%5B%5D=Paper

When I remove '%5B%5D' from the url it all works fine and I get my results. '%5B%5D' stands for '[]' in URI encoding, can't figure out where that come from though. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Best,
Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [reference](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/text_field) how `text_field` and [reference](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/text_field_tag) for `text_field_tag` helper works:

```
<%= text_field :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search..." %>
```

It will give you search input field with `name=search[]`, thats why its passing `search[]='text'`.

```
<input type="text" name="search[]" placeholder="Search..." />
```

Use `text_field_tag` instead:

```
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search..." %>
```